# Como posso forçar a atualização de um estado no React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

Eu tenho em uma tela 4 inputs que enquanto são preenchidos, com o onChangeText os seus valores serão somados, para que esta soma possa ser subtraída com o valor total da compra e mostrar em um input, os valores restante de tudo em tempo real. [Imagem do app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEStN.png)

Meu principal problema nisto tudo é que o useState contém um delay e realmente só atualiza quando o usuário insire outro dado no input.

```
const [dinheiro, setDinheiro] = useState(0)

<TextInput style={styles.InputCompletar} 
  onChangeText={async(din)=>{
   await setDinheiro(din);
   getValorRestante(dinheiro)
  }}           
  keyboardType='numeric'>  
</TextInput>
```

Se der um console.log no resultado que a getValorRestante(dinheiro) ira receber, sempre será um valor desatualizado.
Como pode ver no proprio exemplo, tentei também usar uma função assíncrona mas também não funcionou.

(Este exemplo de codigo esta sendo usando nos meus 4 inputs )

Gostaria de saber: como eu posso fazer para mandar os valores atualizados para a função poder calcular em tempo real o valor restante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O state no React é assíncrono, este é o único cuidado que vc deve ter quando trabalhar com o state, vc não pode querer atualizá-lo e logo em seguida usá-lo.

```
const [dinheiro, setDinheiro] = useState(0)

<TextInput style={styles.InputCompletar} 
  onChangeText={setDinheiro}
  keyboardType='numeric'>  
</TextInput>
```

Chamando a função que atualiza o estado dentro do componente, sem a função assíncrona que vc fez, acontece um ciclo de re-renderização que garante que o estado vai ser atualizado, mas fazendo dentro da função, nem sempre ele atualiza à tempo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ai no caso eu chamaria a função de somar por fora? Tipo, dentro do useeffect por ex

Comment: Sim, aí no caso de vc usar um useEffect, toda vez que o componente for re-renderizado, ele vai chamar a função.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, sucesso!